# HTML table inside jQuery dialog box positioning

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I've created a dialog box with a ajax load call inside the dialog box. I'm trying to place a html table inside the dialog box, but when i load the page, the html table appears way down below where it should be, which is at the top of the page. How can I get the HTML table to show at the top of the dialog?

```
    $("#subscribe").button().on( "click", function() {

        $( "<div id='subscription_d' title='Please Enter Your Details'></div>" ).dialog({
                width:400,
                height:250,
                autoOpen: true,
                resizable: true,
                modal: true,
                open: function(event, ui) {

                    $('#subscription_d').load("ajax.php?action=subscribe_form", function (){
                        $(this).find('button').button();
                    });

                },

        });
});
```

This then calls the ajax.php file, and the code for that is:

```
<?php

switch ($_GET['action']){

case 'subscribe_form':

    $html = '';
    $html .= '<form id="formsignup">
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>(something here)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
              </form>';

    echo $html;

break;


default:

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the dialogClass and position parameter , if you haven't.

```
$( "<div id='subscription_d' class='mydialog' title='please Enter Your Details'></div>" )
   .dialog({
     width:400,
     height:250,
     autoOpen: true,
     resizable:true,
     modal:true,
     dialogClass: "mydialog",
     position: { my: "left top+50 " ,  of :"#subscribe" },
     open: function(event, ui) {

        $('#subscription_d').load("ajax.php?action=subscribe_form",     function(){
            $(this).find('button').button();
        });
     }
  });


.mydialog {
    border : 1px solid #555;
    float : left;
    z-index: 10;
}
```